# Android sign apk from gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle

I used android studio to generate sign APK (build->generate sign APK).
both V1 and V2 checkboxes were marked in the signature version.
To upload an APK via CI-CD, I am running assemleRelease cmd.
The problem is that the sign from assembleRelease is different (probably it's signed with V1 only).
How can I run assembleRelease to sign with the same signature as android studio (build->generate sign APK)?

my code:

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('../config/xx.jks')
        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(file("../local.properties")))
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "my-alias"
        keyPassword "password"
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
    debug {
        storeFile file("../Config/xx.keystore")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, The path from the studio linked to another key-store file (not the one the "storeFile file('../config/xx.jks')" linked to..

Answer (score 0):

Before this you can check the `gradle.propertices` file

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file path of key
            storePassword password
            keyAlias my-alias
            keyPassword password
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }
```